# revitpythonshell is not update from 2018 to 2019

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I had download rps setup file "2019.09.19_setup_RevitPythonShell_2019.exe" from https://github.com/architecture-building-systems/revitpythonshell

But RevitPythonShell version is still 2018.0.0 as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiuoT.png)

The reason why I want update, even I installed IronPython 3.4.1, .Net 4.8 . That is not work now and I Think RevitPythonShell problem.
Because I checked version through CMD that IronPython and .Net version are correct.

Other computher I used before, RevitPythonShell is not same above, and it was work well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRTCx.png)

I installed IronPython 3.4.1, .Net 4.8 and I installed "2019.09.19_setup_RevitPythonShell_2019.exe"

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an images.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions under the heading [RevitPythonShell  Installation](https://github.com/architecture-building-systems/revitpythonshell#installation) to install a more recent version.

Comment: Thank you for kind response. however It was not solved yet.....
Above issue is also happend on latested version, But I re-installed from https://github.com/architecture-building-systems/revitpythonshell/releases/tag/2.0.2